# DependencyProperty Change Background Colour with Bool

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I try to change my background color of a custom control rectangle.
If my property (bool) `setSelected==true` the colour should be `Red`.
If `setSelected==false` it should be `Transparent`.

How can I change my binding background color of the `Rectangle`?

Generic:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:IdnStatusRect}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:IdnStatusRect}">
                <Border Background="Transparent"
                        BorderBrush="Purple"
                        BorderThickness="0">
                    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15" Height="15" Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle Width="15" Height="15" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="#97CDEB" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                            <Grid.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="{Binding Path=BackgroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Offset="0" />

                                </LinearGradientBrush>

                            </Grid.Background>

                        </Grid>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

StatusRect:

```
public class IdnStatusRect : Control
{
    public bool setSelected
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(setSelectedPropert); }
        //  set { SetValue(RectPropert1, Application.Current.FindResource(value.ToString())); }
        set { SetValue(setSelectedPropert, value); }
    }
    
    public static readonly DependencyProperty setSelectedPropert =
        DependencyProperty.Register("setSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(IdxButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    public Color BackgroundColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(setSelectedPropert); }
        set { SetValue(BackgroundColorProperty, FindResource("TextColor1")); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundColorProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundColor", typeof(Color), typeof(IdxButton), new PropertyMetadata((sender, args) => {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Set bg col");
                }));

    static IdnStatusRect()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(IdnStatusRect), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(IdnStatusRect)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a trigger to your control template that monitors the `SetSelected` property. You would need to assign an `x:Name` to the `Rectangle`, so you can refer to it in the setter with `TargetName`.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:IdnStatusRect}">
   <Border ...>
      <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15" Height="15" Background="Transparent">
         <Grid>
            <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionRectangle" Fill="Transparent" .../>
            <!-- ..other markup. -->
         </Grid>
      </DockPanel>
   </Border>
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="SetSelected" Value="True">
         <Setter TargetName="SelectionRectangle" Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
      </Trigger>
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

A different option is to use a style for the `Rectangle` with a relative source binding.

```
<Rectangle Width="15" Height="15" Stroke="#97CDEB" StrokeThickness="1">
   <Rectangle.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
         <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SetSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:IdnStatusRect}}}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

Please consider aligning your dependency properties to the conventions.

- Properties should be defined in Pascal Case (starting with a capital letter)
- Dependency Property names must end with `Property`.
- The owner type `IdxButton` does not correspond to the control type `IdnStatusRect`.
- A wrapper property for a dependency property must not contain other code than getting and setting the value with the corrsponding methods, since they can be set using the dependency property itself, bypassing your custom code. Use a property changed callback in the dependency property definition instead if needed at all.
- **Tip:** Refer to the wrapper property name with [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) instead of hardcoded strings.

```
public bool SetSelected
{
   get => (bool)GetValue(SetSelectedProperty);
   set => SetValue(SetSelectedProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SetSelectedProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SetSelected), typeof(bool), typeof(IdnStatusRect), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
```